# What does it mean that the capability for observing properties is available to variables?

Tags: swift

In the Swift documentation (Properties-Property Observers / Global and Local Variables), it is stated

> The capabilities described above for computing and observing properties are also available to global variables and local variables.

I understand how to use `willSet` and `didSet` in classes, but what does the above mean with regard to global and/or local variables?

---

Update: It means you can do this (if you remember that an explicit type is required):

```
var someGlobalString: String = "abc" {
    willSet {
        println("someGlobalString changing from \(someGlobalString) to \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        println("someGlobalString changed from \(oldValue) to \(someGlobalString)")
    }
}
someGlobalString = "qrs"
```

and see this in the console:

```
someGlobalString changing from abc to qrs
someGlobalString changed from abc to qrs
```

I think this is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you can use the observer for local/global vars as well

```
func test() {
    var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
        willSet(newTotalSteps) {
            println("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
        }
        didSet {
            if totalSteps > oldValue  {
                println("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
            }
        }
        }

        totalSteps += 1
    }
test()
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using an explicit type on my variable and didn't have live issues on so missed why I was failing (and, of course, resorted to stackoverflow before putting in much effort :-)). Have to say I find this to be a nice feature.